# como mostrar imagenes alojadas en servidor Express Node?

Tags: nodejs, api, imagen, express

Estoy desarrollando una api en express y nodeJS. Ademas de eso tengo una carpeta con imagenes que esta relacionada a un documento guardado en mongoDB, no tengo ningun problema al consultar los datos. Pero no logro obtener la imagen por medio de la URL:

`http://localhost:3000/imagenes/Q5l_15xBI0hhm-iyaT6hMCvm.jpg`

el resultado que obtengo en el navegador es:

`Cannot GET /imagenes/Q5l_15xBI0hhm-iyaT6hMCvm.jpg`.

Ya cree la ruta para ese directorio de esta forma:

```
app.get('/:img', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile( `imagenes/${img}` );
});
```

y use el Middleware static de express:

```
app.use(express.static('imagenes'));
```

para el directorio, pero me sigue apareciendo el 404 y no logro mostrar la imagen.

---

Aclaración: la carpeta que contiene las imágenes esta al mismo nivel que mi archivo js que ejecuta esto

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema estuvo en una tontería, la URL dice:

```
http://localhost:3000/imagenes/Q5l_15xBI0hhm-iyaT6hMCvm.jpg
```

y la ruta dice:

```
/:id
```

la ruta omitía la ruta **/imagenes**

Answer (score 0):

en realidad tu código es correcto nada mas hace falta de donde se encuentra el archivo

```
app.get('/:img', function(req, res){
res.sendFile( __dirname+`/imagenes/${img}` );});
```

asi es como se hace correctamente